# Vpython. Any way to get a file dialog?

Tags: python, vpython

I'm designing a local client that will display some pointclouds. I want to add a file dialogue for local uploads. However, the read_local_file just isn't known in the vpython library. Any way to go about doing this? Like is there a way to have a file explorer on a navigation pane?

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/GlowScriptDocs/files.html

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: This is a Python question, not really a VPython question. Search for "Python file dialog".